# Setting up FTP with freeNAS and router

Tags: ftp, freenas

I have some problem to access my FTP from outside.

I am trying to do this with no knowledge ta start with. Hopefully Im doing some rookiemisstake here.

I have set up my NAS to port 21. (open in router)
I have minimum and maximum passive port set up. (open in router)
I have set up masquerade IP (external IP)
I can access to the FTP when I try with filezilla when Im using local server IP. Even with windows explorer it works.

When I try to connect thrue external IP, filezilla get the catalogs in my FTP, but then it enters passive mode and shuts down.

Spend a lot of hours googling it, but cant find any answers.

I put my hope to all the great minds in here!

Comment: Hi Daniel, did you open tcp/20 as well? Remember 21 is the control port, but the data port is 20, both have to be open

Comment: Yes, forgot to write that. Port 20 is open. Tried to forward it NAS port 21 and tried to forward to 20 (dont know which one is correct)

Comment: I can add that the connection is broken after MLSD command

Comment: Did you try this? https://serverfault.com/a/493117/353867

Comment: Cant find that setting in my filezilla.

Comment: It says this, Spårning: CFtpControlSocket::TransferParseResponse()
Spårning: CFtpControlSocket::SendNextCommand()
Spårning: CFtpControlSocket::TransferSend()
Kommando: MLSD
Spårning: CTransferSocket::OnConnect
Fel: Anslutningens tidsgräns överstegs efter 20 sekunders inaktivitet (inactivity)
Spårning: CFtpControlSocket::ResetOperation(2114)

Comment: Found it. Now it says "PORT MY,IP,NUM,BER,5,241", "CFtpControlSocket::OnReceive()
", "500 Illegal PORT command". (What does 5,241 stands for?? 6 sections in IP)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get filezilla to work. My main issue is solved,  and that was to sync pictures from my phone to my NAS. 
Downloaded AndFtp to my phone,  and from that app it worked fine!